# How to call an async task inside a timer?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I figured out how to use a repeat a normal method with a timer, and it worked fine. But now I have to use some async methods inside of this method, so I had to make it a Task instead of a normal method. This is the code I currently have now:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    Timer t = new Timer(5000);
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    t.Start();
}

private async Task OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I am currently getting an error on the `t.Elapsed +=` line because there is no await, but if I add it, it simply acts as if it was a normal func, and gives me a missing params error. How would I use this same Timer but with an async task?

Comment: `OnTimedEvent` is an event handler. That is one exception where `async void` is allowed. change the method to `async void` and await your async tasks within. The `Test` method however is not async.

Comment: See also [the 1200+](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+async+event+handler) other related questions that already address this scenario.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For event handlers you can go ahead and use `async void` return type. Your code should look like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    Timer t = new Timer(5000);
    t.AutoReset = true;
    t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    t.Start();
}

private async void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: By the way there is a small mistake here as the delegate function ElapsedEventHandler actually looks like this: 
`public delegate void ElapsedEventHandler(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);` 

So you should change your OnTimedEvent to be: 
`OnTimedEvent(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Which timer is this using? Please specify the namespace for this timer.

Comment: looking at the signature @zapnologica I would expect System.Timers.Timer